# How to make this pattern in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```

This is the pattern. Have to use flow control (if, for, else if, etc.). Can't just print it or write it one by one. My code so far is:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int x;

    for(int y = 1; y < 9; y++){
      for(x = 1; x < 9; x++){
        if(x > 8 - y){
          Stairs(true);
          Stairs(false);
        }

        else{
          System.out.print("|  |");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void Stairs(boolean odd){
      System.out.print("|" + ((odd)? "<3" : "##") + "|"); 
  }
}
```

This is the output. I am having trouble figuring out the problem

```
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##| 
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```

Comment: I don't think even or odd will work.  See that the pattern alternates?  You have to take that into account. (You might be able to use the distance from that diagonal as even or odd though.)

Comment: @markspace IIRC even and odd also alternate.

Comment: You have a loop that iterates 8 times, and then inside that loop you have another loop that loops 8 times. But in that nested loop, if `x > 8 - y` then you print **two** columns. In effect, you are printing twice as many columns than needed.

Comment: @Slaw how do I fix that? If i set it to 4 then it doesn't do the desired output. I am really confused and new to Java and I appreciate your help.

Comment: You need another if-else inside that `if (x > 8 - y)` block that determines if you print `"|##|"` **or** `"|<3|"`, not both. Note that could manifest itself as a **single** `Stairs(condition)` call, where you have to figure out what `condition` to test for (in this case, the if-else is in the `Stairs` method).

Comment: If that is your output, you are likely very close. Looks like if you figure out why your lines are too long, you would have it solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the code I modified based on yours:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int x;
        boolean flag;
        for(int y = 1; y < 9; y++){
            for(x = 1; x < 9; x++){
                if(x > 8 - y){
                    flag = true;
                    do{
                        Stairs(flag);
                        x++;
                        flag=!flag;
                    } while(x<9);
                } else{
                    System.out.print("|  |");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void Stairs(boolean odd){
        System.out.print("|" + ((odd)? "<3" : "##") + "|"); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKdL5.png)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... This is the output. I am having trouble figuring out the problem"*

I've run the code, and it appears to fail because of the *inner-loop* values.

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String s1 = "<3", s2 = "##";
boolean b;
for (int i = 7, j; i >= 0; i--) {
    s.append("|  |".repeat(i));
    b = false;
    for (j = i; j < 8; j++)
        s.append("|%s|".formatted((b = !b) ? s1 : s2));
    s.append("%n".formatted());
}
```

Output

```
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Here's your code slightly refactored:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfSteps = 8;
        for (int y = 1; y <= numberOfSteps; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfSteps; x++) {
                if (x > numberOfSteps - y) {
                    System.out.print("|<3|");
                    System.out.print("|##|");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("|  |");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives this (wrong) output:

```
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```

The two `for` loops are iterating *for each "step"*. That means for every iteration of the inner `for` loop, you should only be printing out *one* step. But the above will print *two* steps for every non-empty step. That behavior comes from:

```java
System.out.print("|<3|");
System.out.print("|##|");
```

The code needs to be modified so that only `|<3|` **or** `|##|` is printed, not both at the same time.

Looking at the expected output, we can see that the "steps" alternate both in the horizontal direction and the vertical direction. In the code, we have access to `x` and `y`. These two numbers are also alternating between even and odd. And if we look at the values of `x` and `y` for each step we'll see a pattern. A `|<3|` will only be printed when `x` is *odd* and `y` is *even*, or vice versa<sup>1</sup>. In other words, a `|<3|` will only be printed when `x` and `y` have *different [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics))*.

Using that knowledge, we can modify the original code to give us<sup>2</sup>:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfSteps = 8;
        for (int y = 1; y <= numberOfSteps; y++) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= numberOfSteps; x++) {
                if (x > numberOfSteps - y) {
                    if (x % 2 != y % 2) {
                        System.out.print("|<3|");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("|##|");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("|  |");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Which now gives us the expected output:

```
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```

---

<sup>1. When `x` and `y` start at `1`.</sup>

<sup>2. The `%` is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo). A number `n` is even if `n % 2 == 0`; it's odd if `n % 2 == 1`. So, if `x % 2 != y % 2`, then `x` and `y` have different parity (i.e., one is even and the other is odd).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another one, but this version asks for how many stairs:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many stairs? ");
    int numStairs = sc.nextInt();
    if (numStairs >= 1) {
      for(int row=1; row<=numStairs; row++) {
        boolean heart = true;
        for(int col=1; col<=numStairs; col++) {
          System.out.print("|"); 
          if (col <= (numStairs-row)) {            
            System.out.print("  ");            
          }
          else {
            System.out.print(heart ? "<3" : "##");
            heart = !heart;
          }
          System.out.print("|"); 
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Number of stairs must be greater than or equal to one!");
    }
  }
  
}
```

Sample run:

```
How many stairs? 8
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|  ||  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
|  ||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3|
|<3||##||<3||##||<3||##||<3||##|
```